# Redux adding new item to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have two cases in my reducer:

```
case GET_CODE:
    return {
      ...state,
      list:[...state.list,{code: action.payload.product.Code}]
    } 
case WEIGHT:
      return {
        ...state,
        list:[...state.list,{weight:action.payload}]
      }
```

My state is looking like this:

```
   list: [
          { weight: ''},
          {weight: '100'},
          {weight: '200'},      
          {code: '63'},
          {code: '64'}   
         ]
```

What i would like to have is something like:

```
   list: [
          {weight: ''},
          {weight: '100', code:'63'},   
          {weight: '200', code:'64'}  
        ]
```

My initial state is `list:[]` . First empty value of weight is from initial render i think.I dispatch first WEIGHT then GET_CODE action.

Answer (score 0):

You should write some sort of helper function that creates the object for you, or the code/weight case should find the object in `list` it should correspond to.

For the helper function:

```js
const createObject = (code, weight) => {
  const obj = {code: code.product.Code, weight: weight}
  dispatch({type: 'ADD_TO_LIST', payload: obj});
} 

// In your reducer
case ADD_TO_LIST:
  return {
    ...state,
    list: [
      ...state.list,
      action.payload
    ]
  }
```

Or just use ADD_TO_LIST case and create the object in the reducer

i.e.

```js
case ADD_TO_LIST:
  return {
    ...state,
    list: [
      ...state.list,
      {code: action.payload.code.product.Code, weight: action.payload.weight}
    ]
  }
```